# Monitoring WiFi connection status and reconnect if frozen

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Toshiba laptop that for some reason keeps freezing its wireless connection. It would connect just fine, work for hours with no problems, and then just freeze, needing a disconnect-reconnect to the wireless network.

Is it possible to make a script (or use an existing tool) to monitor the internet connection, and if the connection is down, cycle the connection?

Comment: In my opinion, It's wifi driver issue. You should update that driver.

Comment: I will try that, I'll use this as a plan B, if it still keeps freezing, because the laptop needs constant connection while unattended.

Comment: No, it is not practically possible. You don't have access to the api of the front end controlling the card through a driver. If it was Linux where the driver was made by Linux community you could do it from a bash script. Buy a new card by recommendation it is stable for the encryption you like to use. The Wireless market is filled with crooks who only thinks about earning fast money, but without deliver at a reasonable quality. If you are to listen to a recommendation, the card should have been carefully tested in an hostile environment with a lot of AP's in the band you plan to use.